# QueryStrings from an Email

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have generated a *QueryString* and sent it in an email for approval:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234;">Accept</a>
```

The email sending process works.  It arrives at Outlook but when I press "Accept" I get the following error:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.117.222.18:25
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code."

In Accept.aspx I use the following statements to evaluate the Querystring:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     Dim id1 As String
     id1 = Request.QueryString("id")
 End Sub
```

In the error it says I have to send something back or "properly respond".

How does that work?

Comment: Have you tried changing the href to `http://www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234;`? Also, have you tried to remove the semicolon at the end?

Comment: Yes tried both of them: http://www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234 is how I originally put it in as, sorry for the typo.  I then tried: url = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("http://www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?ids=" + ids1)

Answer (score 0):

First try adding the protocol to the URL. Change it to `http://www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234;` and it should work.

Right now it's treating the URL as if it was local to the computer that is opening the email.  (Effectively, it's looking at `http://localhost/www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234;`.)  By adding the protocol you'll point it in the correct direction.

Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll give you another tip for troubleshooting it further.

Update:  Just noticed something.  Your IP address looks like includes a port (25).  Why is your SMTP server answering HTTP requests?

Comment: The http://www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234 is coming from an "a href" from an email.  When it is click in the email it goes to the site but times out for some reason?

Comment: I understand, but you generate the URL and the email, correct?  You're going to need to add the protocol to that URL in order for it to work.

Comment: Does going to http://www.mysite.com/Accept.aspx?id=1234 in your browser work? (if you copy and paste it?)

Comment: No going to the site in the browser does not work. What protocol do i need to add?

Comment: Ok, so it's not the email link - it's the site itself. Have you deployed Accept.aspx to the mysite.com server?

Comment: Yes Accept.aspx is in the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44950/discussion-between-dave-mroz-and-teledextri)